# Thymeleaf display checkbox only if checked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring project, I am displaying a list of checkboxes from database and the checked boxes are displaying correctly. But along with checked boxes, unchecked boxes also getting shown.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<label for="deptLoc">Dept Location</label>                                                                
<div class="input-group" th:each="deptLoc: ${DevApproach}" >                                                                                                                                                                        
<input type="checkbox" th:value="${deptLoc.id}"  th:field="*{deptLocations}" disabled/>

</div>                                                                                
</div>
```

How can I show only the checked checkboxes ?

Comment: do you have an attribute that says this is checked or not by the user?

Comment: @slimane No. While displaying, checkboxes get checked based on the values stored in the database

Comment: did you try to add a simple condition to your logic based on those values in db?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
<input th:if="${deptLoc.id == true}" type="checkbox" th:value="${deptLoc.id}"  th:field="*{deptLocations}" disabled/>
```